# Branch io: Setup custom domain for universal link

Tags: ios, branch.io

I'm stucking at `Domain is incorrectly set up; please use the nameservers below as your NS record`.
But before setup NS record, i want confirm something because the custom domain i'm using is belong to my client.

So when user click `mydomain.com` (not `.app.link` or anything from Branch), does app open? If user don't have app, does AppStore open?

2nd question: How do i edit AASA file? I want some link open app, some link open web.
My current path in AASA file: `"paths": ["/catalog/*", "NOT /blog/*.html", "/blog/*"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any domain, be it branch link or not needs to configured in the android manifest file so as for it to be a supported link for the app. 
All supported links will open the app directly (if the user has the app).
For ios, these have to be declared in associated domains.
All App Links and Universal links help in improving customer experience by directly opening into the app.

It is possible to edit the AASA file as per your use case. You would need to raise a ticket to support@branch.io regarding your request and this will be answered to.

You can look into our documentation here so as to understand better : https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/advanced-settings-configuration#section-change-link-domain